# Temporarily exclude all internationalization .resx files in Winforms app

Tags: winforms

I am using resx files for internationalization of my Winforms app. For each form I manually set the .Localizable Property to True.

I also have a Strings.resx file that I use for messageboxes etc.

How can I temporarily (!) disable the localization and just use the neutral language?

I would prefer not setting the threadculture to the neutral language.

Thanks

Comment: *I would prefer not setting the threadculture to the neutral language.* ← Why? (You can rename/remove satellite assemblies folder/files, but before considering it as a solution, I'd like to know what prevents you from following the most straightforward solution?)

Comment: I forgot to mention that this app runs inside of another application. If I set the threadculture I might unintentionally also change the language of the main application.

Comment: Assuming it's like a referenced assembly, or a plugin which runs in the same UI thread, then you can stop distributing your satellite assemblies.